# Invalid Signature for MySQL repository

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, apt, apt-get

I really hope you can help me as i've tried to find a solution myself for like 3 hours or so.
I basically went through every stackoverflow post there was regarding this.

What i'm trying to do is i want to `apt-get update` on my Debian Linux 10 environment.

Every time i try to run this this comes up:

```
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt stable InRelease [3,566 B]
Get:2 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease [6,771 B]
Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt stable InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5
Get:3 https://packages.sury.org/php buster/main i386 Packages [282 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 
A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried everything i found on stackoverflow and on the MySQL forum.
I really hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had to install MySQL on Ubuntu through a different method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259242/unable-to-install-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 30):

Was getting similar error

```sh
Err:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
Fetched 20.0 kB in 1s (26.1 kB/s)
```

Try to remove the previous key and add it again:

```sh
$ sudo apt-key list

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2021-12-14 [SC] [expires: 2023-12-14]
      859B E8D7 C586 F538 430B  19C2 467B 942D 3A79 BD29
uid           [ unknown] MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
sub   rsa4096 2021-12-14 [E] [expires: 2023-12-14]
```

```sh
sudo apt-key del A4A9 4068 76FC BD3C 4567  70C8 8C71 8D3B 5072 E1F5
```

```sh
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29
```

After that `sudo apt-get update` is working fine.

Comment: +1 because your answer was part of the solution. However, for deleting the key, you'll have to put it in quotes because of the space characters. For example: `sudo apt-key del 'A4A9 4068 76FC BD3C 4567  70C8 8C71 8D3B 5072 E1F5'`

Comment: Just worked without quotes for me?

Answer (score 4):

Considering that the *mysql-server* on your machine is installed through APT repositories, you can solve this problem by installing [MySQL's APT configurator](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/).

Apparently, the **GPG key is reconfigured** once `mysql-apt-config.deb` is installed.

---

*Resources: [upgrading mysql though APT repositories](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-upgrading)*

Comment: Download the aforesaid .deb file, installed it using dpkg and tried updating. The problem's gone! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar problem and found an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141364/957431). The signature key expired.

Try running the following command:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5`

Comment: When i try that this comes back:

`Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.00F6EFHTL2/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5
gpg: key 8C718D3B5072E1F5: 3 duplicate signatures removed
gpg: key 8C718D3B5072E1F5: "MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
`

And then apt-get update still doesn't work.

Comment: @RootK1d I'm getting the same error as you with the `unchanged: 1` and the update doesn't work. were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```bash
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should importing a completely different key resolve the problem?

Comment: Not sure why, but this is the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers provided worked for me. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, but I need to run MySQL 5.7. This was possible using an older mysql-apt-config (0.8.24-1). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232558/install-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04 - the post mentions 0.8.10, but it works up to 0.8.24.

After October 2023, this method will not work because the PGP key used is not public or has been forgotten to be published.

However, you can manually import the PGP key:

```
wget -qO - https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023 | sudo apt-key add -
```

(see https://repo.mysql.com/ for a list of available keys, choose the most recent one)

After that, `apt-get update` works again, however mysql-apt-config was updated to the latest version in the process. I had to remove it and re-install mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb from my local copy.

Comment: I can't access wget without a apt-get update... so how do you first wget to be able to use apt-get update?

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting wget isn't everywhere. curl works too (`curl -O https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023`), or you fetch the file via browser and copy it to the server manually.

Once the file is on the server, cd to the location and import it like this:
`cat RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023 | sudo apt-key add -`